# willFinishLaunchingWithOptions seems to get no options from interactive local notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am troubleshooting an issue where my app does not respond to an interactive local notification or show any indication that it has received the notification. As best I can see, the app's `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is triggered, but there are no `launchOptions` passed in. Here's my code:

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    NSLog(@"will finish launching last time launched was %@", [[[CoreManager sharedManager] userDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastTimeLaunched2"]);
    [[[CoreManager sharedManager] userDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"lastTimeLaunched2"];
    [[[CoreManager sharedManager] userDefaults] synchronize];

    NSLog(@"will finish launching most recent launch options are %@", [[[CoreManager sharedManager] userDefaults] objectForKey:@"launchOptions2"]);
    if(launchOptions) [[[CoreManager sharedManager] userDefaults] setObject:launchOptions forKey:@"launchOptions2"];
    else [[[CoreManager sharedManager] userDefaults] setObject:@"no launch options" forKey:@"launchOptions2"];
    [[[CoreManager sharedManager] userDefaults] synchronize];

    return YES;
}
```

When I launch the app *after* interacting with a local notification, the log indicates the correct time for 'last time launched was'...as the time that I interacted with the local notification *but* launchOptions seems always to be nil. If there are no launchOptions, how can my code react to the user's action in a local notification?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look at `application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler:` and `application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification: withResponseInfo:completionHandler` which handle your app being launched from local notifications.

And, `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` which handles receipt of local notification when your app is active.